# Add Radio Button GROUPS to sortable list

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have 2 sortable lists.  When I drag content over to the other list I want to append a radio group to the list item.

SAMPLE LISTS (sortable1 has no list items until moved from sortable 2)

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
</ul>

 <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
```

When I move a list item from sortable2 to sortable1 I want to append a radio group to the list.

The JQUERY that appends 3 radio buttons to sortable 1:

```
$( "tbody.connectedSortable" ).sortable({   
receive: function( event, ui ) // add radio boxes on drop
 {

                ui.item.append("<input type='radio' name='test' value='test1'><input type='radio' name='test' value='test2'><input type='radio' name='test' value='test3'>");
                //console.log ("");

 },
```

**QUESTION:
How do I dynamically add UNIQUE names to the radio groups?** The code above adds the radio buttons, but all of the radio buttons are the same group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a variable global like this:

```
var countGroup = 0;
```

and in append, do this:

```
$( "tbody.connectedSortable" ).sortable({   
receive: function( event, ui ) // add radio boxes on drop
 {

                ui.item.append("<input type='radio' name='group"+ countGroup +"' value='test1'><input type='radio' name='group"+ countGroup +"' value='test2'><input type='radio' name='group"+ countGroup +"' value='test3'>");
                 countGroup = countGroup +1;
                //console.log ("");

 },
```

if you want to get values do this:

```
function getSelectedRadioButtons(){
       for(var i = 0; i <= countGroup; i++){
         console.log($("input[name=group" + i + "]:checked").val());
       }
```

}